# Mapper_parsing_exception : Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch [version 6.4.0].I am trying to index a simple customer document into the customer index.My query is

```
  curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'
{
  "name": "John Doe"
}
'
```

> 

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "failed to parse"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "failed to parse",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "not_x_content_exception",
      "reason" : "Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below command..

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty -d "{\\"Name\\":\\"John Doe\\"}"
```

Comment: With two backslashes didn't work. But with one backslash it worked (at least there came other errors in my case :D )

Answer (score 0):

you cant send value like this :

**Wrong way :**

```
{
  "name": "John Doe"
}
```

Its bad approach bcz elastic search need any data at a particular key.

**Correct Way :**

```
{
 "results": 
     {
      "name": "John Doe"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/customer/_doc -d '{"name":"John Doe"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```